# Optional keyref in xsd?

Tags: xml, xsd, keyref

Is it possible to define an attribute in xsd so that it may have an empty value but is checked to refer to another element when there is a value?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TableStructure xmlns="tmp/TableStructure"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="tmp/TableStructure TableStructure.xsd">
  <Column name="a" />
  <Column name="b" />
  <Column name="c" />
  <Range name="r1" fromColumn="a" toColumn="b" /> <!-- works -->
  <Range name="r2" fromColumn="a" toColumn="" /> <!-- should work -->
  <Range name="r3" fromColumn="a" /> <!-- works -->
  <Range name="r4" fromColumn="" toColumn="c" /> <!-- should work -->
  <Range name="r5" fromColumn="foo" toColumn="bar" /> <!-- should not and does not work -->
</TableStructure>
```

I tried the following Schema:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="tmp/TableStructure" elementFormDefault="qualified"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            xmlns="tmp/TableStructure"
            xmlns:ts="tmp/TableStructure">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace"
                schemaLocation='http://www.w3.org/2009/01/xml.xsd' />

    <xsd:element name="TableStructure">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1">
                <xsd:element ref="Column" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
                <xsd:element ref="Range" maxOccurs="unbounded" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:key name="columnName-key">
            <xsd:selector xpath="./ts:Column" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@name" />
        </xsd:key>
        <xsd:keyref name="fromColumn-ref" refer="columnName-key">
            <xsd:selector xpath="./ts:Range" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@fromColumn" />
        </xsd:keyref>
        <xsd:keyref name="toColumn-ref" refer="columnName-key">
            <xsd:selector xpath="./ts:Range" />
            <xsd:field xpath="@toColumn" />
        </xsd:keyref>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Column">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>

    <xsd:element name="Range">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" use="required" />
            <xsd:attribute name="fromColumn" use="optional" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="toColumn" use="optional" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Can I use the selector/field to somehow exclude empty attributes?

I'm trying to create a schema for existing files and would prefer not to have to change them to remove empty attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the keyref feature doesn't allow you to treat attributes whose value is a zero-length string differently from other attributes.

XSD tends to be a bit paternalistic in that it only allows you to describe designs that the XSD designers considered to be good practice, and I imagine that the designers of XSD would be telling you that you should omit the attribute here rather than having it present with an empty value.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this. It's not ideal, but I can work with this and won't waste more time trying to find a workaround.